# How do I check if the number of occurrences of two words in a String is Equal without using loops?

Tags: java, string, compare

I am trying to find out if there is the same number of occurrences `"dog"` and "cat" are in the given `String`.

It should return `true` if they are equal, or `false` otherwise. How can I find out this **without** `while`, `for` etc. loops?

This is my current process

```
class Main {

    public static boolean catsDogs(String s) {
        String cat = "cat";
        String dog = "dog";
        if (s.contains(cat) && s.contains(dog)) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean r = catsDogs("catdog");
        System.out.println(r); // => true
        System.out.println(catsDogs("catcat")); // => false
        System.out.println(catsDogs("1cat1cadodog")); // => true
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can use appache library then StringUtils.countMatches should go good for your case

Comment: "without while, for etc loops" but why? Are you looking for some hacky way like `s.split(cat,-1).length == s.split(dog,-1).length` (please note that each `split` still uses some kind of loop internally)?

Comment: Hey thank you very much for ur comment its working perfectly now. Im currently at the start of my computer science lessons at uni and my prof wants it to be like that. Only god knows why :D probably to not confuse others with loops because it wasn't mentioned to much for now idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example by replacing the string (in case you don't want the split to be placed) :

```
public static boolean catsDogs(String s) {
    return count(s,"cat") == count(s,"dog");
}

public static int count(String s, String catOrDog) {
    return (s.length() - s.replace(catOrDog, "").length()) / catOrDog.length();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean r = catsDogs("catdog");
    System.out.println(r); // => true
    System.out.println(catsDogs("catcat")); // => false
    System.out.println(catsDogs("1cat1cadodog")); // => true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With java9+ the regex matcher has a count method:

```
public static boolean catsDogs(String s) {
    Pattern pCat = Pattern.compile("cat");
    Pattern pDog = Pattern.compile("dog");
    Matcher mCat = pCat.matcher(s);
    Matcher mDog = pDog.matcher(s);
    return (mCat.results().count() == mDog.results().count());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of single-line solutions based on Java 9 [`Matcher.result()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) which produces a stream of `MatchResult` corresponding to each matching subsequence in the given string.

We can also make this method more versatile by providing a pair of regular expressions as arguments instead of hard-coding them.

## teeing() + summingInt()

We can turn the stream of `MatchResesult` into a stream of strings by generating matching groups. And collect the data using collector [`teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) expecting as its arguments two *downstream collectors* and a *function* producing the result based on the values returned by each collector.

```
public static boolean hasSameFrequency(String str,
                                       String regex1,
                                       String regex2) {
    
    return Pattern.compile(regex1 + "|" + regex2).matcher(str).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.summingInt(group -> group.matches(regex1) ? 1 : 0),
            Collectors.summingInt(group -> group.matches(regex2) ? 1 : 0),
            Objects::equals
        ));
}
```

## collectingAndThen() + partitioningBy()

Similarly, we can use a combination of collectors [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) and [`partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)).

The downside of this approach in comparison to the one introduced above is that `partitioningBy()` materializes stream elements as the values of the map (*meanwhile we're interested only their quantity*), but it performs fewer comparisons.

```
public static boolean hasSameFrequency(String str,
                                       String regex1,
                                       String regex2) {
    
    return Pattern.compile(regex1 + "|" + regex2).matcher(str).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.partitioningBy(group -> group.matches(regex1)),
            map -> map.get(true).size() == map.get(false).size()
        ));
}
```